# Print Value to a Column of Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA and I have the following bit of code working right now:

```
Do
    monsterFinalDmg = monsterDmgFunction((Int(2 * Rnd)), ((Int((6 * Rnd) + 1))), (    ((Int(2 * Rnd)) * 8)), ((Int((26 * Rnd) + 75)) / 100))
    currentPlayerHP = (currentPlayerHP - monsterFinalDmg)
    playerFinalDmg = playerDmgFunction((Int(2 * Rnd)), ((Int((8 * Rnd) + 1))), (((    Int(2 * Rnd)) * 10)), ((Int((16 * Rnd) + 70)) / 100))
    currentMonsterHP = (currentMonsterHP - playerFinalDmg)

Loop Until currentMonsterHP <= 0 Or currentPlayerHP <= 0

If currentMonsterHP >= currentPlayerHP Then
    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Value = monsterWinner
    Exit Sub

Else
    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Value = playerWinner
    Exit Sub
```

I would like to specify a range of cells (B2:B11) on that Sheet that this Do loop prints its result to each cell rather than just A1.

Comment: What data type are your variables, `Integer`, `Double`, or `Single`?

Comment: I suggest changing the loop to `While-Wend` in case this gets called when `hp=0` already.

Comment: Just curious, what do the damage functions look like, and how is `currentMonsterHP` and `currentPlayerHP` initialized?

Comment: I'll try the while wend.

Comment: Oh and hp I statically set

Comment: Put `` between the code to format with `code`. See [help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Ipskp9pOVi_w8JPeg0HxImAad9gocltdE3Vnz29jqfM/edit?usp=sharing

^ the whole sub

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: Working on it now for while wend.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that you can extend:

```
Dim output As Range
Set output = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B1")

Do
    monsterFinalDmg = monsterDmgFunction((Int(2 * Rnd)), ((Int((6 * Rnd) + 1))), (    ((Int(2 * Rnd)) * 8)), ((Int((26 * Rnd) + 75)) / 100))
    currentPlayerHP = (currentPlayerHP - monsterFinalDmg)
    playerFinalDmg = playerDmgFunction((Int(2 * Rnd)), ((Int((8 * Rnd) + 1))), (((    Int(2 * Rnd)) * 10)), ((Int((16 * Rnd) + 70)) / 100))
    currentMonsterHP = (currentMonsterHP - playerFinalDmg)
    output.Value = "value you want to output"
    Set output = output.Offset(1)
Loop Until currentMonsterHP <= 0 Or currentPlayerHP <= 0

If currentMonsterHP >= currentPlayerHP Then
    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Value = monsterWinner
    Exit Sub

Else
    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Value = playerWinner
    Exit Sub
```

Comment: I want to output playerWinner or monsterWinner which are strings.  I am not seeing how it would know which to output until the if / else at the end.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to repeat this calculation for ten cells

Try this:

```
Public Sub Fight10Times(ByVal currentMonsterHP As Double, ByVal currentPlayerHP As Double)
    Dim results() As Variant
    '10 trials, with 3 columns. Winner, playerHp, mosterHp
    ReDim results(1 To 10, 1 To 3)
    Dim i As Integer, monster_hp As Double, player_hp As Double
    For i = 1 To 10
        'initialize hp values from given
        monster_hp = currentMonsterHP
        player_hp = currentPlayerHP
        ' One fight. True of player won, and modifies
        ' monster_hp, player_hp to final values
        If CheckWinner(monster_hp, player_hp) Then
            result(i, 1) = playerWinner
        Else
            result(i, 1) = monsterWinner
        End If
        results(i, 2) = player_hp
        results(i, 3) = monster_hp
    Next i
    ' Setting value on range of cells writes entire array with one operation.
    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B2").Resize(10, 3).Value = results

End Sub

' Arguments are byref because function modifies them and we want to keep the results
Public Function CheckWinner(ByRef currentMonsterHP As Double, ByRef currentPlayerHP As Double) As Boolean
    While currentMonsterHP > 0 And currentPlayerHP > 0
        monsterFinalDmg = monsterDmgFunction((Int(2 * Rnd)), ((Int((6 * Rnd) + 1))), (((Int(2 * Rnd)) * 8)), ((Int((26 * Rnd) + 75)) / 100))
        currentPlayerHP = (currentPlayerHP - monsterFinalDmg)
        playerFinalDmg = playerDmgFunction((Int(2 * Rnd)), ((Int((8 * Rnd) + 1))), (((Int(2 * Rnd)) * 10)), ((Int((16 * Rnd) + 70)) / 100))
        currentMonsterHP = (currentMonsterHP - playerFinalDmg)

    WEnd
    'True if player wins
    CheckWinner = currentPlayerHP > currentMonsterHP
End Function
```

The trick it to put all the values you want in a array of `Variants` and use the `Range().Value =` assignment.